# Implementing colorpicker in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, color-picker

I am using richfaces but it lacks colorpicker componenet. I found colorpicker in [standbox](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/4XSandboxComponents#jive_content_id_ColorPicker)
release of richfaces but I am unable to use it. How do I use it? Are there any other alternative **colorpicker** component?

```xml
<rich:dataTable id="addeditdtable" 
      value="#{Lecontroller.LeType.LeList}" var="Le" >

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Upper Range"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{Le.upperrange}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Color"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText class="makemecolorpicker" value="#{Le.color}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ADD/Delete"/>
        </f:facet>
        <a4j:commandLink value="Add" 
             actionListener="#{Lecontroller.addLeDTO()}"  
             render="Leform:addeditdtable"/>
        <h:outputText value=" / "/>
        <a4j:commandLink value="Delete" 
             actionListener="#{Lecontroller.removeLeDTO(Le)}" 
             render="Leform:addeditdtable"/>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

This is rich datatable or jsf datatable with dynamic row addition. One of the column represents colorpicker where I should be able to pick a colour and save it.

Comment: May you add more description about your code implementation.